# Editing obsecure html page value before sending

Tags: automation, robotframework

Is there a way to edit specific html page value directly with Robot Framework?

(Like you would open a browser DevTools and edit some specific obscure value.)

Example:

Html-page has this element:

```
<option value="98021">First Selection</option>
```

and robot framework would directly change the value number to something else before clicking button on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how good it works but there is an XML Library in which you can set the attribute of an element.

So in this case it would be:

Set Element Attribute   |  xpath   |  value   |   ValueYouWantToChangeTo

Here is the link to it: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Set%20Element%20Attribute

Comment: Hey Thanks for the response.
Doesn't this feature only work for external .XML files that you have downloaded? and not for opened HTML page on the screen.